Circuit Schematics for water level controller

I'm a beginner here. I am trying to build a water level controller. This is my multisim schematic. I am trying to use a switch that would play the part of water and the LED will turn on when the water is below the level. My multisim schematic is not turning the LED on. I am also using a relay (12 VDC).

You've told us a bunch of things, but not actually asked a question. Please ask a specific, answerable  question. See the help section on how to ask a good question

You don't have a power supply for the LED.  The relay contacts are just a switch - by themselves they don't apply any power to the load.
As you have drawn it, the relay contacts willl just provide a short circuit across the LED and resistor when closed.

Your no inverting input on the op amp is floating when the switch is open.  That's not a great idea, even when using the op amp as a comparator. There are leakage currents that need a place to go. Tie the non inverting input to ground through a large resistor.
Also, your LED has no power supply.

Also, your op amp doesn't have a power supply.
